# Dispatches an action from different component [react-boilerplate]

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

I am using [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) to create a react project.

I have two different components:

In component A has a saga function that should be also called in component B.

When I dispatch an action from component A, the saga function is called correctly, but when I dispatch the same action from component B (I am sure the action is dispatched), the saga function in component A is not called.

Anyone has idea why this happens?

Maybe the actions can not be dispatched from other components?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that calling the function in B should make another function also be called in A? And which purpose should this have? Also it would be helpful if you provide some example code to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call async function that located in other containers, we should include the saga which contains the async functions.

```
import homeSaga from './saga';
import loginSaga from '../loginPage/saga';

const withHomeSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'home', saga: homeSaga });
const withLoginSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'login', saga: loginSaga });
export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withHomeSaga,
  withLoginSaga,
  withConnect,
)(HomePage);
```